# What's the best way of handling ViewModel destroying for CancellationToken activation with MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, mvvmcross, viewmodel

I am having an MvvmCross ViewModel, which calls different async methods of my DataService.
Similar to the following:

```
public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IIdentityService _dataService;
    private CancellationTokenSource _viewModelCancellationTokenSource;
    public IMvxCommand GoLogin { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel(IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _dataService = identityService;
        _viewModelCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        GoLogin = new MvxCommand(async () => await ProcessLogin());
    }

    private async Task ProcessLogin()
    {
        // calling the dataservice which must stop processing
        // (to cancel) in case if the ViewModel is being destroyed
        await _dataService.AssureIsLoggedIn(data, _viewModelCancellationTokenSource.Token);
        await NavigationService.Navigate<LoginNextStepViewModel>();
    }

    public override void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing = true)
    {
        base.ViewDestroy(viewFinishing);

        // not sure if that is a right (and working) place
        _viewModelCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

So, MvvmCross is quite unclear about the part with the ViewModel destroying. It describes `Construction, Init, Reload and Start`, but doesn't say any definite regarding the `destroying`:

> Monitoring other View/ViewModel lifecycle event across multiple
>   platforms is fairly tricky, especially once developers start
>   experimenting beyond the ‘basic’ presentation models and start using
>   tabs, splitviews, popups, flyouts, etc
>
> For most viewmodels, it’s common to not try to monitor other lifecyle
>   events. This is OK since most viewmodels don’t perform any actions and
>   don’t consume any resources when the view is not present - so these
>   can just be left to be garbage collected when the system needs the
>   memory back.

However, besides the custom platform situations, there are still many cases like navigating back from the view model, or (again) navigation away from current viewmodel with its following closing.

So, what's the best way to handle it then?

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```cs
// calling the dataservice which must stop processing
// (to cancel) in case if the ViewModel is being destroyed
```

The ViewModel won't be destroyed before the async methods finish executing. I think you are confusing the View with the ViewModel.

In case of a login page, you would usually prevent the user from navigating away from it until your server call goes through.

If for some reason you want to cancel then you need to decide what scenarios you want to handle, there is no single universal place. Your options are the view callbacks:

```cs
void ViewDisappearing();
void ViewDisappeared();  
void ViewDestroy();
```

and the navigation events:

```cs
event BeforeNavigateEventHandler BeforeNavigate;
event AfterNavigateEventHandler AfterNavigate;
event BeforeCloseEventHandler BeforeClose;
event AfterCloseEventHandler AfterClose;
event BeforeChangePresentationEventHandler BeforeChangePresentation;
event AfterChangePresentationEventHandler AfterChangePresentation;
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I can't see it's quite an answer to my question: a) the point of the question is not `destroying` itself, but cancelling the `CancellationToken` in particular cases, like navigating out of the view or the ViewModel destroying; b) every app has its own logic: this is rather critical on the web not to cancel the service call because of possible issue with cookies, but in mobile other cases possible;

Comment: c) I don't see any (my) confusion with View: ViewModel is coupled with View by MvvmCross to simplify some operations, so, that's quite natural that ViewModel going to be destroyed when navigating out from view (at least); but at the same time, again, MvvmCross is very careful to the ViewDisappearing-like events, saying that it might be unsafe when using for all the platforms. So, that's why I've created this question in general: to clarify possible (safe) ways of guaranteeing current ViewModel would notify about the end of its lifecycle.